# My DJango app is responding to /static urls

Tags: django, python-2.7

**Update**

I figured out what was causing the stylesheets to become invisible, though I don't quite understand it all. I set DEBUG=False in settings.py to test the error handling as described in the tutorial. Somehow setting debug to false causes the static files not to be locatable. I will look further in the configs to see if I can get a clear understanding why. Until then, please feel free to answer or comment with additional info. I am still learning!

**Update**

I'm going through a DJango tutorial from [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/intro) and I hit a roadblock. I'm up to tutorial 3 where they explain how to refactor your urls.py file when I try loading up the admin site to make sure I haven't broken it. Sure enough it looked all wierd because it was missing the stylesheets. Stylesheets are pulled from here:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/admin/css/base.css
```

When I hit that link in my browser I get the custom 404 page I configured for my app. The stylesheets were working prior but I'm not sure which change broken them. I went through my urls.py file and reverted all of the polls specific url configs to no avail. Here's my current urls.py under hellodjango (the name of my project.)

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

# Uncomment the next two lines to enable the admin:
from django.contrib import admin
from django.http import HttpResponse

admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^polls/', include('polls.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)

def page_not_found(request, template_name='404.html'):
    return HttpResponse("Could not find the resource you asked for...")

handler404 = 'hellodjango.urls.page_not_found'
```

and here's the urls.py under my polls directory:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url

# Uncomment the next two lines to enable the admin:

urlpatterns = patterns('polls.views',
    url(r'^$', 'index'),
    url(r'^(?P<poll_id>\d+)/$', 'detail'),
    url(r'^(?P<poll_id>\d+)/results/$', 'results'),
    url(r'^(?P<poll_id>\d+)/vote/$', 'vote'),
)
```

Help?

Comment: read through [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/howto/static-files/)

Comment: Thanks but my question to you is the same as what I posted to Peter below.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you don't have a URL pattern for `/static`. As such, the `static/admin/css/base.css` URL doesn't match any pattern, and so you get a 404. Try something like this:

```
from django.conf.urls.static import static

# ...
urlpatterns = patterns('',
# ...
                       url(r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',
                           {'document_root': settings.STATIC_ROOT}),
# ...
```

This should work for you -- go to `/static/foo.css`, and you should see your CSS.

It's worth noting that this is discouraged in a production environment. For your tutorial app, though, it'll work.

Comment: Thanks, but let me play dumb. Why was it working before and what caused it to break? Also do I need to set a value for STATIC_ROOT in my settings.py?

Comment: Still doesn't work, I tried importing settings from hellodjango, my project root and from django.conf.

Comment: This answer is incorrect, anyway. You shouldn't need to serve your static files via the urlconf (however you may want to do it for uploaded files - aka `MEDIA_URL` / `MEDIA_ROOT`).

Comment: I figured out what causes the static files to be unreachable. I've updated my post.

Answer (score 0):

The staticfiles app provides a custom `runserver` management command that automatically serves the static files, are you sure you have the following in your settings?

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    # ...
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
)
```

In production, you'll use the `collectstatic` management command that finds all of the static media and dumps it into `STATIC_ROOT` (this is the only purpose for this setting - it isn't used or needed during development).

Comment: Yes it is there. I figured out what was causing the issue. I will update my question above.

Answer (score 0):

Glad you figured it out. Here's why it works like this.

`django.contrib.staticfiles` overrides the `runserver` management command so that the static files are served automatically. To remind people that they shouldn't be using django to serve static files, this only happens when `DEBUG = True`, as you found out.

The [documentation of the overridden management command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#staticfiles-runserver) explains that you can use the `--insecure` flag to make this work no matter the state of the `DEBUG` setting.